# Ubuntu 13.04 lts doesnt recognize my 500gb external hard disk

Tags: 13.04, usb, hard-drive

Previously i had windows 8 installed and changed back to Ubuntu, i think Ive messed up the hdd drive (freecom 500gb)

Comment: Would you please edit the original question to provide some more information on the exact nature of the problem?  Do you have the Ubuntu installation on the external drive, or elsewhere, and are unable to mount the external drive from there?  Also, please provide any errors, or attempts you performed to resolve the issue on your own.

Comment: Im still a noob operating linux:/, ive reedit it because i was at version 12.04 and then ive sucessfully updated to 13.04 using a bootable dvd, also i didnt try anything yet

Comment: Ive converted the hdd drive to ntfs using windows 8 maybe that is the problem i was messing with diskpart via cmd

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, based on your additional comments:

If you converted your Ubuntu partion into an NTFS formatted drive, then yes, your Ubuntu installation will no longer work, regardless of whether it was on an external HDD or not.

It sounds like you're going to probably need to start over.  Ubuntu would want (by default) an ext4 formatted drive.